# Using Rethinkdb's change feed in a webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rethinkdb

How can I use Rethinkdb's change feed in a webapp, see http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/ruby/ ? I currently use Ruby on Rails. I've tried Googling 'rethinkdb "change feed" rails' and 'rethinkdb "change feed" websocket'

I would like to display updates on a webpage to a RethinkDB table with lowest latency as possible.

Comment: What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: I want to display the changes to the table.

Comment: No just display the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RethinkDB seems to not support complex client authentication (auth token is shared amongst all clients), so you can't do that client-side from Javascript.

But you can create a pipeline: run websocket on your server, which will fetch records from RethinkDB and pass it to clients. Using [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) it will look something like this:

```
require 'em-websocket'
require 'rethinkdb'
include RethinkDB::Shortcuts

EventMachine.run do
  @clients = []
  @cursor = r.table("authors").changes.run

  EM::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => '3001') do |ws|
    ws.onopen do |handshake|
      @clients << ws
    end

    ws.onclose do
      @clients.delete ws
    end

    @cursor.each do |document|
      @clients.each{|ws| ws.send document}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

RethinkDB is meant to be used from the server (from Rails) and not from the client. It's really important to understand this! If you have a listener on your data (a changefeed), then hose changes will get routed to your Rails app.

If you want to add to query RethinkDB from the front-end (from the browser), you might be interested in these two projects:

https://github.com/mikemintz/rethinkdb-websocket-client

https://github.com/mikemintz/rethinkdb-websocket-server

Once these changes are routed to your application, then you can do with them as you wish. If what you want to do is route those changes to the front-end to just show the users these changes, you can just send them through a web socket. Faye is a really good library to do this.

This is how this would look like. In your ruby code, you would add something like this:

```
 # Add Faye
  App = Faye::RackAdapter.new MessageApp, mount: "/faye"

  # Changefeed listener
  r.table("messages").changes.em_run(Conn) do |err, change|
    App.get_client.publish('/message/new', change["new_val"])
  end
```

Basically, whenever there's a change in the `messages` table, send the new value over the web socket. You can take a look at the full example (with front-end code) here:

https://github.com/thejsj/ruby-and-rethinkdb/

And here is the Ruby file:

https://github.com/thejsj/ruby-and-rethinkdb/blob/master/server/main.rb